# Overriding hashCode() not working

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, hashset

I'm trying to make class `Point` work correctly with a HashSet. Here is my Point class:

```
class Point {

    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int x, int y) {
        x = x;
        y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 1;
        hash = hash * 17 + x;
        hash = hash * 31 + y;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }
        Point p = (Point) o;
        return x == p.x && y == p.y;
    }
}
```

When I test it out and do

```
    HashSet<Point> h = new HashSet<Point>();
    h.add(new Point(0, 0));
    Point g = new Point(0, 1);
    System.out.println(h.equals(g));
    System.out.println(h.contains(g));
```

The output is this

```
false
true
```

Why is my hashCode not working?

Comment: Why would a `HashSet<Point>` equal a `Point`?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel doh. I wasn't thinking. Let me fix it and test

Comment: Your bug is in the constructor.  It does nothing.   (And Sotirios beat me to it ... again)

Comment: Your equals() method is incorrect. It should not throw a ClassCastException if something other than a Point is passed as argument. It should return false instead.

Comment: Question - does the constructor work? Doesn't defining the parameters as x and y override (or is it shadow/hide?) the global class variables? Wouldn't it then be like assigning a variable to itself?

Answer (score 7):

In

```
Point(int x, int y) {
    x = x;
    y = y;
}
```

You are assigning `x`, the local parameter variable, to itself. Same for `y`. These are no-ops.

Use

```
Point(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

so that you assign the parameter value to the field.

---

As [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134928/overriding-hashcode-not-working#comment33585834_22134928) have noted, you shouldn't do

```
Point p = (Point) o;
```

without knowing if `o` is a `Point` or not. It will throw a `ClassCastException` if it is not assignable to a `Point`. Instead use

```
if (o instanceof Point)
    return false;
```

or

```
if (o.getClass() != Point.class) 
    return false;
```

before casting. Note that the two methods above are not equivalent. You can use the first in most cases, but use the second if `Point` is meant to have sub classes.

Comment: Thanks! I was being careless ><

Comment: +1, @OP: Use an IDE, that warns you, to prevent this in future.

Comment: Fixed the instanceof. Thanks again guys

Comment: Mostly a really good answer.  But I have to disagree with the last sentence.  Whether `Point` is meant to have subclasses should not be the criterion for choosing whether to use `instanceof` or `getClass()`.  It's whether it makes sense for an object of one of those subclasses to be equal to a `Point`.  As an example, if you look at the `equals` method of `AbstractList`, it uses `instanceof`, and `AbstractList` definitely has subclasses.  But this is deliberate, because it makes sense for an `ArrayList` to be equal to a `LinkedList`, if the elements are all the same.

Comment: @DavidWallace I'll link to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162188/java-equals-method-in-base-class-and-in-subclasses) to explain the reasoning for my suggestion. As for `List`, I think it's a special case. The `List` interface declares a `equals()` method with javadoc saying `Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal.` So, based on the spec, any `List` can be equal to any other `List`. This might not be true for other types where other fields might play into it.

Comment: Actually, I think of `List` as being the rule, rather than the exception.  I would expect this kind of behaviour whenever we have multiple implementations of the same interface.  If two objects are both of types that implement a particular interface, AND the two objects are indistinguishable in terms of methods from that interface, then they're effectively equal, and should return `true` when compare with `equals()`, even if their implementations are different.  Looked at another way, the behaviour of `equals()` should be defined by what the interface is, not by what the implementation is.

Comment: @DavidWallace I accept all of that. `List` says what the rule is for its implementations. And it's easy enough to do that with `List` because of the various interface methods. But is a `Point2D` equal to a `Point3D` and vice versa? If you do `point2d.equals(point3d)` where they have equal x and y coordinates, the method might return true, but the inverse is not true, since a `Point3D`  would probably want to compare the z dimension as well.

Comment: I think you and I are actually in loud agreement.  `Point` and `Point3D` are basically value objects - they're not alternative implementations of a common interface.