# java - equals method

Tags: java, object, equals

There is an **Employee class** and a class called **Manager that extends Employee**. The two have same fields, but `Manager` has one extra field called `bonus`. The `equals` method for Manager is:

```
public boolean equals(Object otherObject){
    if(!super.equals(otherObject) 
        return false; 
    Manager other = (Manager) otherObjetc;
    return this.bonus == other.bonus;
}
```

We create `employeeObj` and `managerObj` as an instance of Employee and Manager class respectively, such that all their fields are identical (except the bonus which employeeObj doesn't have at all).

Then if we call the  managerObj.equals(employeeObj) does the if condition return false? if the answer is 'no', then do we get any error for the cast or the line after it because employee doesn't have a bonus field?

The book that this example is from claims that super.equals checks if this and otherObjetc belong to the same class. But I think they didn't take into account that the method will throw exception if we pass to it an instance of employee class. Correct me if i am wrong...

Here is the equals method for employee class:

```
public boolean equals (Object otherObjetc){
    if (this==otherObjetc) 
        return true;
    if (otherObject == null) 
        return false;
    if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass()) 
        return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) otherObject;
    return name.equals(other.name) && salary==other.salary
}
```

Comment: `employeeObj.equals(managerObj)` may return true, but `managerObj.equals(employeeObj)` will always return false

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162188/java-equals-method-in-base-class-and-in-subclasses

Comment: By the definition of equals, `a.equals(b)` and `b.equals(a)` must return the same result. So if Manager extends Employee, then a Manager can be used in place of an Employee without error thanks to polymorphism. The above code, while it will compile and run, is invalid because it violates the contract of the equals method.

Comment: Show the `super` implementation please.

Comment: @Tezra If OP tries to sort a mixed list of Employee and Manager objects (and the list is big enough), "Timsort" could very likely throw a "Contract Violation" exception due to the `a.equals(b)` but `b.notEquals(a)` issue coded into the equals method above. (Because compareTo() and hashCode() are written to return consistent results with equals() right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then if we call the managerObj.equals(employeeObj) does the if
>   condition return false?

Yes, it shall return false.

> if the answer is 'no', then do we get any error for the cast or the
>   line after it because employee doesn't have a bonus field?

No, you wouldn't get a ClassCastException, since

```
if(!super.equals(otherObject)) return false;
```

completes the execution and returns anyway and you do not reach

```
Manager other = (Manager) otherObject;
```

which can possibly throw a class cast exception.

Test code with some sample fields defined in the Employee and Manager models:

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setName("null");
employee.setSurname("pointer");
Manager manager = new Manager();
manager.setName("null");
manager.setSurname("pointer");
manager.setBonus(10);
System.out.println(manager.equals(employee));
```

***Edit***: The reason why

```
!super.equals(otherObject)
```

evaluates to **true** and ultimately return false is because within equals of its super class

```
if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass()) return false;
```

`getClass()` (evaluates to Manager) and `otherObject.getClass()` (evaluates to Employee) are both difference classes.

Comment: Why would if(!super.equals(otherObject) return false? The two objects have identical fields except that bonus is not defined for employee class. Doesn't this line check the equally of all fields except bonus? Then it should return TRUE. right?

Comment: `super.equals(otherObject)` will return true if it uses `instanceof`.

Comment: It doesn't. i will edit the question to include the equals method for the employee as well.

Comment: @MehrdadFarsadyar That would depend on the implementation of equals in the super class(Employee) in your case. Also as pointed by shmosel, if it uses instanceof internally, it might return True as well. My bad, I just shared one assuming an example of what I was trying to create.

Comment: @shmosel Agreed. Would now await the edit by OP to get things clear.

Comment: @MehrdadFarsadyar Updated the answer with the updated equals for Employee class.

Comment: @nullpointer thank you for your answer. My mistake was that I thought the getClass() returns the class for the super class (so Employee) and not the class for managerObjetc.

Comment: @MehrdadFarsadyar welcome. I hope it helps. Not sure why is the answer still downvoted thouhgh :)

Comment: I downvoted originally because it was unsubstantiated. Upvoted now.

Answer (score 0):

If you cast an object that is not a `Manager` to `Manager`, you will get an exception.

This is why Java is type-safe.

Comment: that is what i thought too, but this is an example from a book and maybe I am wrong but it seems to me they didn't take this into account!

Comment: @MehrdadFarsadyar: If they're different types, `super.equals()` will return false.