# Equals method when dealing with inheritance and no instance variables

Tags: java, inheritance, equals, instance-variables

This is the way we implement equals method in classes.

Class A (Store) with area as instance variable:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
    if (this == otherObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (otherObject == null || getClass() != otherObject.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Store otherStore = (Store) otherObject;

    return area == otherStore.area; 
}
```

Class B (StoreToys) extends Class A (Store) and has no instance variables (dealing with inheritance)

How should i write equals method for this class?

Comment: `getClass() != otherObject.getClass()` why are you doing this instead of `instanceof`?  `getClass` is something that Effective Java explicitly warns you not to do because it breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - equals method in base class and in subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162188/java-equals-method-in-base-class-and-in-subclasses)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't introduce any new fields in `StoreToys` you can write the check with `instanceof` to verify that `otherObject` can be cast to `Store`.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
  if (this == otherObject) {
    return true;
  }
  if (!(otherObject instanceof Store)) {
    return false;
  }
  Store otherStore = (Store) otherObject;
  return area == otherStore.area; 
}
```

Comment: you need a ! on`instanceof`