# Equals method in child class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ to auto generate the `equals` and `hashCode` function for following two classes.  I found in the `Dog` class' `equals` method, it is doing

```
if (this == o) return true;
if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
```

Should these two lines be omitted since they're in the parent class? I thought when calling `super.equals()`, those checks would happen in the parent class.

```
class Animal{
    String eye;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Animal animal = (Animal) o;
        return Objects.equals(eye, animal.eye);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(eye);
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    String hair;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
        Dog dog = (Dog) o;
        return Objects.equals(hair, dog.hair);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), hair);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those lines *could* be omitted, since the call to `super.equals` will actually validate if the objects are the same instance, or if they're not the same type.

[Just...be *very* careful about doing this at all with subclasses.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13162188/1079354)  It's not something that's commonly done for inherited types since equivalence isn't the same as an **is-a** relationship (for instance, a `Dog` **is-an** `Animal`, but not all `Animal`s are `Dog`s, and defining equivalence for them all seems strange; two animals are not the same because their eyes are brown).

Comment: Thx for reminding this, in my actual case base class "Animal" is an abstract class which can't be instantiated, have equals there because many fields are in base class and not want to include all fileds in all sub classes