# What should be the result of overridden "Object#equals(Object)" when instance is upcasted?

Tags: java, liskov-substitution-principle, upcasting, object-comparison

I am, specifically concerned with obeying the **symmetry** part of the general contract established in `Object#equals(Object)` where, given two non-null objects `x` and `y`, the result of `x.equals(y)` and `y.equals(x)` should be the same.

Suppose you have two classes, `PurchaseOrder` and `InternationalPurchaseOrder` where the latter extends the former. In the basic case, it makes sense that comparing an instance of each against the other shall return consistently `false` for `x.equals(y)` and `y.equals(x)` simply because a `PurchaseOrder` is not always an `InternationalPurchaseOrder` and therefore, the additional fields in `InternationalPurchaseOrder` objects will not be present in instances of `PurchaseOrder`.

Now, suppose you **upcast** an instance of `InternationalPurchaseOrder`.

```
PurchaseOrder order1 = new PurchaseOrder();
PurchaseOrder order2 = new InternationalPurchaseOrder();
System.out.println("Order 1 equals Order 2? " + order1.equals(order2));
System.out.println("Order 2 equals Order 1? " + order2.equals(order1));
```

We already established that the result should be symmetric. But, should the result be `false` for cases when both object contain the same internal data? I believe the result should be `true` regardless of the fact that one object has an extra field. Since by upcasting `order2`, access to fields in `InternationalPurchaseOrder` class is restricted, the result of the `equals()` method shall be the result of the call to the `super.equals(obj)`.

If all I stated is true, the implementation of the `equals` method in `InternationalPurchaseOrder` should be something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    
     if (!super.equals(obj)) return false;
     
     // PurchaseOrder already passed check by calling super.equals() and this object is upcasted
     InternationalPurchaseOrder other = (InternationalPurchaseOrder)obj;
     
        if (this.country == null) {
            if (other.country != null) return false;
        } else if (!country.equals(other.country)) return false;

        return true;
}
```

Assuming that `country` is the only field declared in this subclass.

The problem is in the super-class

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    PurchaseOrder other = (PurchaseOrder) obj;
    if (description == null) {
        if (other.description != null) return false;
    } else if (!description.equals(other.description)) return false;
    if (orderId == null) {
        if (other.orderId != null) return false;
    } else if (!orderId.equals(other.orderId)) return false;
    if (qty != other.qty) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Because the two instances are not of the same class. And if instead I use `getClass().isAssignableFrom(Class)`, symmetry is lost. The same is true when using `instanceof`. In the book, Effective Java, Joshua Bloch indirectly warn about overriding `equals` unnecessarily. In this case, however, it is necessary for the subclass to have an overridden `equals` for instances to compare the fields declared in the subclass.

This has gone long enough. Is this a case for a more complicated implementation of the `equals` function, or is this simply a case against upcasting?

**CLARIFICATION**: This question is not answered by the suggestions proposed by @Progman in the comments section below. This is not a simple case of overriding `equals` methods for subclasses. I think the code I posted here shows that I have done this correctly. This post is SPECIFICALLY about the expected result of comparing two objects when one is upcasted so that it behaves like an object of the super-class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - equals method in base class and in subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162188/java-equals-method-in-base-class-and-in-subclasses)

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462/any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals

Comment: @Progman neither of those answer this question.

Comment: @user15244370 I think I know that and I believe I stated that in the post. The question is specifically what should be the result of comparing two objects when one is downcasted.

Comment: Keep in mind that "downcasting" an object doesn't change it's type. The variable `order2` is still referencing an `InternationalPurchaseOrder` object and `order2.equals(order1)` is calling the `equals()` method from the `InternationalPurchaseOrder` class. Which makes the `equals()` method return `false` as of your sentence "[...] shall return consistently `false` for `x.equals(y)` and `y.equals(x)` simply because a `PurchaseOrder` is not always an `InternationalPurchaseOrder` and therefore [...]". How are you planning to return `true` when you also say it should return `false`?

Comment: @Progman that's the philosophical point I am raising. I think the answer is that downcasting is a code smell (for the issue raised here) and that, instead of downcast, the object should be adapted (converted) and not downcasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, the problem is a bit deeper than I originally thought for one main reason: ***Liskov Subsitution Principle***.

My `PurchaseOrder#equals(Object)` method violates LSP. Because `InternationalPurchaseOrder` extends `PurchaseOrder`, it is correct to say that an international purchase **IS-A** purchase order. Therefore, to comply with LSP, I should be able to replace one instance for the other without any ill effects. Because of this, the line `if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;` completely violates this principle.

Even when my focus was around upcasting (which by now I am pretty much convinced that it is a code smell), almost the same issue applies: Should I be able to compare instances of `PurchaseOrder` and `InternationalPurchaseOrder` and return `true` if they contain the same data internally? According to Joshua Bloch book *Effective Java*, Item 10 (Obey the general contract when overriding equals), the answer should be yes, but it is indeed no; but not for the reasons I initially thought (they are not the same type). The problem is this, and I quote:

> **There is no way to extend an instantiable class and add value component while preserving the `equals` contract**, unless you're willing to forgo the benefits of object-oriented abstraction.

He continues to get in more details about this. The conclusion is simple: Do it this way and loose the benefits of abstraction, and violate LSP in the process. Or... simply follow a very important programming principle (especially in Java): **favor composition over inheritance** and inject the attributes you need to make a `PurchaseOrder` domestic or international in this example. In my case, this solution will look like this (irrelevant details of class omitted):

```
public class InternationalPurchaseOrder {
    private PurchaseOrder po;
    private String country;

    public (PurchaseOrder po, String country) {
        this.po = po;
        this.country = country;
    }

    public PurchaseOrder asPurchaseOrder() {
        return po;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof InternationalPurchaseOrder)) {
            return false;
        }

        InternationalPurchaseOrder ipo = (InternationalPurchaseOrder)obj;
        return ipo.po.equals(po) && cp.country.equals(country);
    }
}
```

This way, an `InternationalPurchaseOrder`can continue to be compared to other instances of the same class **AND** if needed to be compared to objects of `PurchaseOrder` type, all that is needed is to call the `asPurchaseOrder` to return an object of the compatible type.

Answer (score 1):

I think the misconception here is that upcasting actually changes the type of an object.

Any type of casting is just a pointer to the compiler to treat a variable as having a certain type, for the developers benefit. So upcasting a variable with type `InternationalPurchaseOrder` to a `PurchaseOrder` might change the way you see it and can interact with it (as you mentioned, fields being restricted), but the variable still references an `InternationalPurchaseOrder`

Therefore to concretely answer your question, comparing classes will use the `equals` method declared to their *actual type*, not the type you have marked it as.

Comment: Right... my point of conflict is that, I can see why so many people consider downcasting a code smell. This might prove that point. On the other hand, when you downcast, you do it for the purpose of masking data in the sublcass. For example downcasting a long to an int. It is as if the purpose is to ignore the upper bytes and just consider the lower bytes. So, if that is true, shouldn't comparing `Long` and `Integer` yield `true` if the values of the lower bytes are the same? Because that is not possible, the only alternative I see is use an Adapter to convert and not downcast.

Comment: I still think this poses an interesting philosophical point.

Comment: @hfontanez: It sounds like you're talking about *upcasting* rather than downcasting. (It's best not to use `int` and `long` for this, given that they're primitives.) Casting something from `Object` to `String` is downcasting; casting from `String` to `Object` is upcasting. The line `PurchaseOrder order2 = new InternationalPurchaseOrder();` is an implicit upcast, from `InternationalPurchaseOrder` to `PurchaseOrder`.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the correction. I should edit the post with that change. I am still inclined to believe that this does more harm than good and that it is indeed a code smell. Instead, the real solution is to use Dependency Injection and use the technique I illustrated in my posted answer. It effectively does what I thought is the right thing to do: Take the "base" set of data and compare the two objects. Using the `asPurchaseOrder` method allows me to do just that. Prefer composition over inheritance!!!